# .NET Core MVC: validate external login without creating account

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to take advantage of Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.MicrosoftAccount in a .NET Core MVC app as explained [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/microsoft-logins), but I would like to skip the storage layer, so that users are not entered in the database.

What I would like to achieve is: ok, my users are just external Microsoft accounts, I don't do any management of them, I just let them login to the app and check, somehow (a list or whatever) which ones are the allowed ones (like john@boo.com can login, and since his identity is verified by the Microsoft account, well, then he can enter).

What I did was to start with the typical

```
dotnet new mvc --auth Individual
```

Them modify it to support Microsoft accounts and that worked.

But, I would like to bypass creating the user in the database, and just log him in. I tried the following:

```
// GET: /Account/ExternalLoginCallback
[HttpGet]
[AllowAnonymous]
public async Task<IActionResult> ExternalLoginCallback(string returnUrl = null, string remoteError = null)
{
    if (remoteError != null)
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, $"Error from external provider: {remoteError}");
        return View(nameof(Login));
    }
    var info = await _signInManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
    if (info == null)
    {
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Login));
    }

    var email = info.Principal.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Email);

    var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = email, Email = email };

    // var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user);

    await _signInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);

    _logger.LogInformation(3, "Microsoft account logged in.");

    return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
}
```

But if I don't do the

```
_userManager.CreateAsync
```

it fails miserably :-S

So, is there a way to achieve this or what I'm trying simply goes against the Identity principles?

Thanks!

Comment: What you actually want is Windows Authentication.  There is no need for Identity management.  In your app, you just use the standard Authorize attribute to give access.  This can be done via role, user, etc..

Answer (score -1):

[This article](http://www.jerriepelser.com/blog/using-aspnet-oauth-providers-without-identity/) show how to use the ASP.NET OAuth providers without ASP.NET Identity, in other words without a DB.